# SQL based on complex criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm struggling with SQL statement that I'm trying to write in MS Access and would appreciate any help.

I have a table:

```
 ***************************
 * attr1 * attr2 *  attr3  *
 ***************************
 *       *  A    *   1     *
 *       *  B    *   2     *
 *       *  B    *   3     *
 *       *  C    *   4     *
 *   B   *       *   1     *
 *   D   *       *   1     *
 *   A   *       *   2     *
 ***************************
```

I need result like this:

```
 ***************************
 * attr1 * attr2 *  attr3  *
 ***************************
 *   B   *       *   1     *
 *   D   *       *   1     *
 *   A   *       *   2     *
 *       *  B    *   3     *
 *       *  C    *   4     *
 ***************************
```

So, I need in my result all rows where attr1 is not null, and all other rows where attr3 has different values from those in rows where attr1 is not null.

I can do it in Access in a way to make one query where I select all rows where attr1 is not null, than one "find unmatched" query where I select all rows with values in attr3 which are not included in first query, and than make union of those two queries... but I need some more direct approach (one sql statement if possible).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably need something like this:

```
Select attr1, attr2, attr3
from table
where attr1 is not null 
      or attr3 not in (select attr3 from table where attr1 is not null)
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, do you see any performance difference with `NOT EXISTS`? ... `SELECT y1.attr1, y1.attr2, y1.attr3 FROM YourTable AS y1 WHERE y1.attr1 IS NOT Null OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable AS y2 WHERE y2.attr3=y1.attr3 AND y2.attr1 IS NOT Null)`

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, I think it just depends on which is more readable / easy to understand to you in that instance.